# Why is there no jar for volley(android)?

Tags: android, android-volley

I use Volley, like others, as networking library in my projects. So in most tutorials, guidelines suggest to clone the project and follow the boilerplate steps to build the project.

Does anybody have any idea, why Google has not built the project into a ready-made Jar file, in order to ease the way?

Comment: "I have to use networking library volley" -- why? "why is there no ready made JAR for volley ?" -- feel free to ask the author of Volley.

Comment: Do you _have_ to use volley? Google are pretty poor at distributing jars. The latest android framework jar on Maven central is 4.1.1.4. All the cool kids are using Retrofit.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I don't know why the author is not providing the jar. Maybe there is a reason to it?? Would there be any issue to have a jar??

Comment: @alex: I assumed that since volley is backed up by Google it would be better. As it turns out I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use Volley in your application, you can use a couple of solutions:

1. Add following dependency to your app's build.gradle file (according to [Android](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) the easiest way):

   ```
   dependencies {
       compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
   }
   ```
2. Cloning the Github repository and then set as a library. For a complete description please refer to [Android developer](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html).

   `git clone https://github.com/google/volley`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using gradle in Android Studio Volley can be added with one line to the gradle.build file's dependencies.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.+'
}
```

If you are using Eclipse, Volley can be added as a library project which will save you having to create a jar.

Comment: Can't volley have a JAR like almost everything??

Comment: Note that this is not an official distribution from Google. Probably it is fine, but it is something to keep in mind.

Comment: @PranavMahajan As volley is free i'm sure the author thought the least people could do is run the ant script for themselves.

Answer (score 0):

If you use git, you can add the volley library project as a submodule by using 'git submodule add'
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/